# Python - How to append the same XML element multiple times with lxml.objectify

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following XML that I am trying to recreate with the lxml.objectify [package](http://lxml.de/objectify.html)

```
<file>
  <customers>
    <customer>
        <phone>
            <type>home</type>
            <number>555-555-5555</number>
        </phone>
        <phone>
            <type>cell</type>
            <number>999-999-9999</number>
        </phone>
        <phone>
            <type>home</type>
            <number>111-111-1111</number>
        </phone>
    </customer>
   </customers>
</file>
```

I can't figure out how to create the phone element multiple times. Basically, I have the following non-working code:

```
    # create phone element 1
    root.customers.customer.phone = ""
    root.customers.customer.phone.type = data_dict['PRIMARY PHONE1']
    root.customers.customer.phone.number = data_dict['PRIMARY PHONE TYPE 1']

    # create phone element 2
    root.customers.customer.phone = ""
    root.customers.customer.phone.type = data_dict['PRIMARY PHONE2']
    root.customers.customer.phone.number = data_dict['PRIMARY PHONE TYPE 2']

    # create phone element 3
    root.customers.customer.phone = ""
    root.customers.customer.phone.type = data_dict['PRIMARY PHONE3']
    root.customers.customer.phone.number = data_dict['PRIMARY PHONE TYPE 3']
```

Which of course only outputs one section of phone information in the resulting XML. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create `objectify.Element` objects, and add them as children of `root.customers`.

For example, inserting two phone numbers can be done like this:

```
phone = objectify.Element('phone')
phone.type = data_dict['PRIMARY PHONE1']
phone.number = data_dict['PRIMARY PHONE TYPE 1']
root.customers.customer.append(phone)

phone = objectify.Element('phone')
phone.type = data_dict['PRIMARY PHONE2']
phone.number = data_dict['PRIMARY PHONE TYPE 2']
root.customers.customer.append(phone)
```

If you get unnecessary attributes on these elements when transforming the xml back to a string, use `objectify.deannotate(root, xsi_nil=True, cleanup_namespaces=True)`.
See [lxml's objectify documentation](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) for exact parameters of `objectify.deannotate`.

(If you're using an older version of lxml, which doesn't include the `cleanup_namespaces` keyword argument, do this instead:

```
from lxml import etree
# ...
objectify.deannotate(root, xsi_nil=True)
etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)
```

)

Comment: Actually, I need to add the 3 phone numbers to one customer, but thanks for the info about the Element object.

Comment: Oops! I've changed my answer accordingly ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some sample code that constructs XML with the [objectify E-Factory](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#tree-generation-with-the-e-factory):

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml import objectify

E = objectify.E

fileElem = E.file(
    E.customers(
        E.customer(
            E.phone(
                E.type('home'),
                E.number('555-555-5555')
            ),
            E.phone(
                E.type('cell'),
                E.number('999-999-9999')
            ),
            E.phone(
                E.type('home'),
                E.number('111-111-1111')
            )
        )
    )
)

print(etree.tostring(fileElem, pretty_print=True))
```

I've hardcoded it here but you can convert to a loop over your data.  Does that work for your purposes?

Comment: I think this would work, but I'd have to re-engineer my code. I may use it for something else though. Thanks!