# How to create the same XML element 3 times with Python LXML Objectify

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I asked a question about adding [multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324128/python-how-to-append-the-same-xml-element-multiple-times-with-lxml-objectify) a couple weeks ago and now I've run into a similar issue. I have to create some XML where I'll have the following:

```
<embossed>
   <line>Test Line</line>
   <line>Test Line 2</line>
   <line>Test Line 3</line>
</embossed>
```

I cannot figure out how to create the same element N times in a row with different text using the LXML objectify.Element() method. I tried this:

```
embossed = objectify.Element('embossed')
embossed.line = objectify.Element("line")
embossed.line = objectify.Element("line")
```

But I end up with only one "line" element inside the "embossed" element. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just append the lines to `embossed`, instead:

```
embossed = objectify.Element('embossed')
embossed.append(objectify.Element('line'))
embossed.line[-1] = 'Test Line'
embossed.append(objectify.Element('line'))
embossed.line[-1] = 'Test Line 2'
```

Each lxml tree tag acts like a list, where any children are elements in the list. Simply appending new `objectify.Element` objects makes them children of the tag you append them to.

You can then reach each element of that list by using indexing; the `-1` index is the last element, allowing us to set it's text.

The above code outputs:

```
>>> from lxml import objectify, etree
>>> embossed = objectify.Element('embossed')
>>> embossed.append(objectify.Element('line'))
>>> embossed.line[-1] = 'Test Line'
>>> embossed.append(objectify.Element('line'))
>>> embossed.line[-1] = 'Test Line 2'
>>> print etree.tostring(embossed, pretty_print=True)
<embossed xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" py:pytype="TREE">
  <line py:pytype="str">Test Line</line>
  <line py:pytype="str">Test Line 2</line>
</embossed>
```

Comment: How do you assign values to the line items then? I'm creating the XML from a flat file and need to assign each line a different value.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: Simply manipulate them like you would any element. I've updated the answer; now I store the newly created `line` element to variable, set the `text` attribute, *then* append it to the parent `embossed` tag.

Comment: ah-ha! I think I must be running an old version of lxml as I couldn't find a "text" property to set or the SubElement method that the other fellow mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: Actually, I just learned that `.text` doesn't work on objectify elements. I've updated the answer.